# Multitasking after changing device date

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, date-and-time, recents-screen, nexus-6p, multitasking

I'm running Android 6.0.1 on a Nexus 6P.

I've been having some trouble with the multitask button, specifically right after changing the device date/time. The multitask button does not work at all, and the home button is sluggish. If I reset to the current time then both begin to work immediately. This behavior does not depend on whether there are other apps open or not.

To reproduce:

1. Go to Date & Time in Settings.
2. Uncheck Automatic date & time.
3. Set date to 2 days before the current time, press "OK".
4. Attempt to use multitask button, which fails.
5. Check Automatic date & time.
6. Multitask button now works!

Anyone else have this problem, or solutions? I'd like to have the multitask button work immediately after changing the date.

Thanks!

EDIT: It worked! I was able to set the date to 2 days prior, and immediate use the multitask button. This only happened once, however, and I can't find a way to reproduce that.

EDIT2: Any ideas?

EDIT3: Multitasking after changing the date seems to work every time when the device is booted in safe mode. So I'm hypothesizing the issue arises from an app I have installed.

Comment: No problems for me on my Nexus 6P (Android N Preview 4).

Comment: Does it consistently work for you? Mine works very very infrequently, and it seems to be random.

Comment: Workshop correctly for me all the time. Do you have any app installed that might cause the problem? Do you have root access?

Comment: I don't have root access; however, I think it works when I've closed all my open apps.